# useLocation() Error with react-router 6 "may be used only in the context of a component."

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, framer-motion

**I try to detect any change that happens to the route so I use the useLocation() hook but it shows Error**

> useLocation() may be used only in the context of a  component.

**When I move it down to any of my components it works but not in my case because I need it to be in App components to detect route change to work with framer motion**

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  Routes,
  RouterProvider,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "./Pages/AuthPages/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./Pages/AuthPages/SignIn";
import Welcome from "./Pages/Welcome/Welcome";
import Homepage from "./Pages/HomePage/Homepage";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/" element={<Welcome />}></Route>
      <Route path="signin" element={<SignIn />}></Route>
      <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />}></Route>
      <Route path="home" element={<Homepage />}></Route>
    </>
  )
);
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Toaster />
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`useLocation` can only be used in context of router

Either move `RouterProvider` up or move `useLocation` down the tree

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  Routes,
  RouterProvider,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "./Pages/AuthPages/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./Pages/AuthPages/SignIn";
import Welcome from "./Pages/Welcome/Welcome";
import Homepage from "./Pages/HomePage/Homepage";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/" element={<Welcome />}></Route>
      <Route path="signin" element={<SignIn />}></Route>
      <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />}></Route>
      <Route path="home" element={<Homepage />}></Route>
    </>
  )
);
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Toaster />
      <RouterProvider router={router}>
        <Component />
      </RouterProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

const Component = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  }, [location]);
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Just FYI `RouterProvider` takes/renders no `children` prop; `Component` won't be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The `useLocation` hook can only be used within a routing context provider, e.g. a router or `RouterProvider` component.

You can abstract the `App` component logic into a layout route that can use the `useLocation` hook and renders an `Outlet` for the nested routes.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "./Pages/AuthPages/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./Pages/AuthPages/SignIn";
import Welcome from "./Pages/Welcome/Welcome";
import Homepage from "./Pages/HomePage/Homepage";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const AppLayout = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Toaster />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Welcome />} />
      <Route path="signin" element={<SignIn />} />
      <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="home" element={<Homepage />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```