# UseLocation error despite wrapping the component in the router tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Im new to react routers and currently using the `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` with the version `react-router-dom": "^6.21.0"`
Im using the  `useLocation()` to dynmaically set a store variable whenever the path changes.

Here is what im doing:

### App.tsx:

```
function App() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const setMode= useStore((state) => state.setMode);
    useEffect(() => {
        setMode(location.pathname.includes(Constants.AppRoutes.IMAGE_PATH));
    }, [location.pathname, setMode]);

    const routesBody = (
        <div className="main">
            <Comp1/>
            <Comp2/>
            <Comp3/>
        </div>
    );

    const routes = [
        { path: "/", element: <Navigate replace to="bla1" /> },
        {
            path: "/bla1",
            element: routesBody,
        },
        {
            path: "/bla2",
            element: routesBody,
        },
    ];

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                {routes.map((route) => (
                    <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
                ))}
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

### Main.tsx:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
       <App /> 
    </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

This setup causes the following error

> Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

### What I did:

Moving the `<BrowserRouter>` tag from the `app.tsx` to the `main.tsx` to make the `main.tsx` look like this:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

While this seems to solve the issue and the routing works it causes all my test cases to have the following clause when rendering otherwise all the test cases will fail to render.

```
render(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>,
        );
```

Why cant i just put the `<BrowserRouter>` in my App.tsx?
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76161963/20496034)

The code looks like this now:

```
const AppLayout = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    //do stuff with the location. 
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div>
            <Comp1/>
            <Comp2/>
            <Comp3/>
    </div>
  );
};

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/bla1"/>} />
      <Route path="/bla1" element={<AppLayout />} />
      <Route path="/bla2" element={<AppLayout />} />
    </>
  )
);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`useLocation` uses a [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) provided by `BrowserRouter`. In order to be able to read from a Context, a component need have the Context provider (in this case, `BrowserRouter`) as an ancestor of the React tree.

As for your test cases, you could either

1. extract some utility function that wraps your App inside `BrowserRouter` for you.
2. Add a layer so that `App` contains `BrowserRouter`:

   ```
   function App() {
     return (
        <BrowserRouter>
           <Root />
       </BrowserRouter>
     );
   }

   function Root() {
      const location = useLocation();
      ...
   }
   ```